# Pattern match and string manipulation

Tags: string, batch-file, file-read

I'm making a file monitor for a folder where I download subtitles. So far, it works like this:

Look for new .rar files in the folder.

If found, extract the subtitles and delete the .rar file

If a single .srt file was extracted, save the file name to a variable.

---

Now, I'm clueless about how to achieve the next (and final) part of the script:

I want to find a pattern based on the way subtitles are named.

Let's say, the subtitles file can be something like this:

SomeShow.1x03.stuff.srt

some_show s01e03-stuff.srt

some show 1-03 stuff.srt

etc.

I want to get something like: SomeShow 1 3 and based on that, start the video with the name that matches that pattern, which I guess would be a matter of reversing the process that was used to get the Show, season and episode based on the name of the .srt file.

Is this possible at all? It'd be really simple stuff in most languages, but I really need this to be a .bat and I'm clueless about how to approach this... so far all I've managed to do is to remove the extension from the variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you write a console program (in C++ for example) and then call this program from your .Bat file (passing the file name as parameters to the .EXE file)? Is that solution a valid one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files are Turing complete - you can do anything in them, but it is usually not wise to go to extremes.  You might be able to package a `sed` or `grep` or your own binary alongside your `.bat` file for a good compromise between batchiness and function.  If you can assume a suitable operating system, you will have Powershell installed and go that route.

You should recognize that the task is not exactly defined and that the "solution" may need some tweaking and be never robust enough.

For this reason, the richer language you can pick, the further you will get.

Comment: I was with you until the last sentence. Having a richer language is of no use at all if the requirements are not well thought out.

Comment: @dbenham - But this task is not rocket science, it will just involve discovery of new naming patterns.  Some may kill the project by being unsolvable (not containing the needed info), others may kill the project by being too complicated to be parsed in the chosen language.  I don't expect a perfect solution to be possible here, ever.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with a different language. If it wasn't clear, what I wanted is some sort of regex functionality for .bat files without the need of external libraries or files; pretty much a stand-alone .bat that would do the whole thing, to be able to turn any subtitle file name into three values: Show name, season and episode and based on that, run another search on the folder and find the video file that matches those values. But yeah, maybe a .bat is not the best tool for the task, specially when I barely know the basics of it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Senekis - As a small puppy I once embedded a short .com executable into the body of a .bat file to do some substep.  It worked but it was nonsense of a tool choice.  I had too much time to spare and no taste I guess.